# the symbol of transformation in Judaism

Tags: symbols-symbology

Would you please telling me about the symbol of transformation in Judaism? By transformation, I meant the upgrade from something earthy, lower in nature to higher, or even sacred entities.

Here are similar examples in the Eastern tradition: a carp can become a dragon when it has the courage to jump over the "dragon gate" located at the top of the water fall in a sacred mountain. Or if a tiger lives up to 500 years, it turns white, and thus becomes a sacred animal, who guards the West, and and has the spirit of metal.

Comment: You are speaking of the transformation between physical to the spiritual? If so, then humans can do this certainly, by taking an object and using it for holy purposes. But I have not heard of any entity doing this on its own without the action of a human.

Comment: Hi, Ariel. Exactly, the transition from physial to spiritual realm. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: But you did not clarify for me: Do you mean by the action of a human, or only an object which does it on its own (perhaps with God's aid, but without the action of a human).

Comment: Ariel, I am looking for the object/animal/tree that does it either on its own, or through the power of God. No human's activities involve here.

Comment: I think I understand this question as trying to apply an entirely foreign concept to Judaism, and therefore so totally outside the scope of the site as to be not a real question. Am I alone on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what kind of symbol you are looking for but the one point of "transformation" in Judaism (other than a circumcision/conversion moment) is a time of communal forgiveness. As the Zohar points out (as referenced in note 9 [here](http://www.ou.org/index.php/jewish_action/article/57327/)) about the high priest, and similarly, it is written about the scape goat [here](http://www.ou.org/chagim/yomkippur/ykavodah.htm), a red thread miraculously turned to white if the atonement rites were successful. Might that changing thread be the symbol of transformation for which you seek?